# How to add initial chunk to informix DB spaces?

Tags: informix

I have a newly created Informix database instance. 
I have following DB spaces.

**

> `RootDBS, temptbs, logdbs, physdbs`

**

I have four chunks. I need to assign them to above DB spaces initially. What is the way to do that? Is there any related documentation about this?  Please mention the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onspaces command to add further chunks to an existing dbspace or to create new dbspaces. Documentation for this can be found in the Knowledge Center at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0561.htm - for example in the sections "Adding a chunk to a dbspace or blobspace" and "Creating a dbspace that uses the default page size."

This is the documentation for Informix version 12.10 but the command syntax is the same in earlier releases.

Answer (score 0):

The initial chunk of the root dbspace, `rootdbs`, is specified in the [`$ONCONFIG`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_286.htm) file (which is located in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc`; see [onconfig file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0008.htm) for documentation on the format) before you initialize the server with [`oninit`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0395.htm).

```
ROOTNAME            rootdbs
ROOTPATH            /opt/informix/dev/osiris_19.rootdbs.c0
ROOTOFFSET          0
ROOTSIZE            1500000
```

The other dbspaces have to be created separately with [`onspaces`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0460.htm) after you've brought the basic server online.

```
Usage:
 onspaces { -a <spacename> -p <path> -o <offset> -s <size> [-m <path> <offset>]
               { { [-Mo <mdoffset>] [-Ms <mdsize>] } | -U }
               } |

          { -c { -d <DBspace> [-k <pagesize>] [-t]
                    -p <path> -o <offset> -s <size> [-m <path> <offset>] } |
               { -d <DBspace> [-k <pagesize>]
                    -p <path> -o <offset> -s <size> [-m <path> <offset>]
                    [-ef <first_extent_size>] [-en <next_extent_size>] } |
               { -P <PLOGspace>
                    -p <path> -o <offset> -s <size> [-m <path> <offset>] } |
               { -b <BLOBspace> -g <pagesize>
                    -p <path> -o <offset> -s <size> [-m <path> <offset>] } |
               { -S <SBLOBspace> [-t]
                    -p <path> -o <offset> -s <size> [-m <path> <offset>]
                    [-Mo <mdoffset>] [-Ms <mdsize>] [-Df <default-list>] } |
               { -x <Extspace> -l <Location> } } |

          { -d <spacename> [-p <path> -o <offset>] [-f] [-y] } |

          { -f[y] off [<DBspace-list>] | on [<DBspace-list>] } |

          { -m <spacename> {-p <path> -o <offset> -m <path> <offset> [-y] |
                            -f <filename>} } |

          { -r <spacename> [-y] } |

          { -s <spacename> -p <path> -o <offset> {-O | -D} [-y] } |

          { -ch <sbspacename> -Df <default-list> } |

          { -cl <sbspacename> } |

          { -ren <spacename> -n <newname> }

    -a  - Add a chunk to a DBspace, BLOBspace or SBLOBspace
    -c  - Create a DBspace, PLOGspace, BLOBspace, SBLOBspace, or Extspace
    -d  - Drop an empty DBspace, PLOGspace, BLOBspace, SBLOBspace, Extspace, 
      or chunk
    -f  - Change dataskip default for specified DBspaces
    -m  - Add mirroring to an existing DBspace, PLOGspace, BLOBspace or 
          SBLOBspace
    -r  - Turn mirroring off for a DBspace, PLOGspace, BLOBspace or SBLOBspace
    -s  - Change the status of a chunk
    -ch - Change default list for smart large object space
    -cl - garbage collect smart large objects that are not referenced
    default-list = {[LOGGING = {ON|OFF}]  [,ACCESSTIME = {ON|OFF}]
            [,AVG_LO_SIZE = {1 - 2097152}] }
    -ren - Rename a DBspace, BLOBspace, SBLOBspace or Extspace
```

The `logdbs` and `physdbs` dbspaces are presumably for the logical logs and the physical log.  Those would be created as normal dbspaces, and then you'd move the logs to those spaces with [`onparams`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0450.htm):

```
Usage:  onparams  { -a -d <DBspace> [-s <size>] [-i] }                      |
                  { -b -g <pagesize> [-n <number of buffers>] 
                   [-r <number of LRUs>] [-x <maxdirty>] [-m <mindirty>] }  |
                  { -d -l <log file number> [-y] }                          |
                  { -p -s <size> [-d <DBspace>] [-y] } 

    -a  - Add a logical log file
    -b  - Add a buffer pool 
    -i  - Insert after current log
    -d  - Drop a logical log file
    -p  - Change physical log size and location
    -y  - Automatically responds "yes" to all prompts
```

The `temptbs` is presumably a temporary dbspace, which you'll end up listing in your $ONCONFIG file too (as `DBSPACETEMP`)

You might end up with (dumb) blob spaces and smart blob spaces too, and you'll probably end up with a temporary sbspace (smart blob space) specified in $ONCONFIG too (as `SBSPACETEMP`).

You can use the [`onmode`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0407.htm) utility to set (some but not all) configuration parameters while the server is running with the `-wf` option, for example.  You could set entries such as `SBSPACETEMP` like that.